# Can't get Data using SwiftyJSON

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) to parse data from URL to JSON Object, but the data is nil.
Here my code

```
 let url = NSURL(string: "http://vietnamnet.vn/jsx/mobileapp/category/?c=quoc-te&p=1")
    var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)
    if data != nil {
        var jsonStr = JSON(data: data!)
        println("data:\(jsonStr)")
    }
```

And Result: `data:null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is malformed.

```
{
    "message": "success",
    lastUpdate: '31/12/2014 09:57:31 (GMT+7)',
    "articles": [{
```

`lastUpdate` is not wrapped as `"lastUpdate"`

And the server is sending a wrong content-type for the response. `text/plain; charset=utf-8` but it should be `application/json; charset=utf-8`.

Comment: Thank to @vikingosegundo The response is malformed, i fix it and solved.